# jQuery: how to make http request with arguments and body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

So I want to make a http request with a body (say `file, file2, file3`) and arguments like `action=delete` how to make such request with jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass parameters with `url` and `files` with body:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl' + '?action=delete',
    type: 'POST',
    data: requestbodyhere,
    success: function(responseData){
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a POST? You can do that using Ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: {
    file1:'file1',
    flie2:'file2'
  },
  success: function(response) {
    //in response you have the answer from the server as a string
  }
});
```

Comment: This is wrong, you can pass parameters by url, no metter it is POST or GET!

Comment: What do you mean? I've forgot to add the ?action=delete, but I'm pretty sure MyWaitJSON can figure that out himself :)